# How can I stop firing SelectedIndexChanged for an ASP listbox using JavaScript or C#

Tags: javascript, c#

How can I stop firing SelectedIndexChanged for a asp listbox on pageload by using javascript or C# ? Based on some conditions in my application user can select listbox item but the event shouldn't be fired. How can we achieve  this?

Comment: are you selecting any item in the listbox in pageLoad

Comment: @vallabha No, he says `the user can select listbox item` and he just don't want that a postback happens then.

Comment: @Jagadeeswararo: If my answer helped you, accept it. The same on your other question where you got the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ListBox`property [AutoPostback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)!

Simply set it to false:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxID" AutoPostback="false">
```

If you want to achieve this from JavaScript you should add:

```
ListBoxID.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return false;");
```